# Android browser: check if opened window is closed

Tags: javascript, android, android-browser

On Native Android browser If I use

```
var win = window.open(...)
```

to open a child window and then use

```
if (win.closed)
```

To check if child window is closed I fail to do so because even when child windows is closed **win.closed** is NOT set to true.

Is there a way to workaround it?

Comment: Seems this has been reported awhile back (guess it's not high on the to-do list): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21061

Comment: You can use browser history to implement this check

Comment: Yes I've seen this 3y old issue.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the solution for this situation:

```
if (win.closed || !win.window)
```

instead of just

```
if (win.closed)
```